# 100% Height Image Responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a full height picture for desktops that as the window resizes the picture resizes and contains proportions.

The issue I am having is if I set the container height to 100% for the desktop version, the div right below the photo doesn't maintain its relationship with the photo because of the height setting on smaller viewports.

Is there a simple fix I am missing that will allow the photo to shrink and the bottom div maintain its spot right below it?

Here is the current code I have running which doesn't output any height at all (I've done other methods but this was my latest)

```
#main-photo {
position: relative;
margin-top: 130px;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}

.featured-photo {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: can you please show us your code snippet? you have given us the css properties if a class and an id. Now which one is the container? some jsfiddle would help. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
html,body {
   height: 100%;
}
```